# Linking a dynamic framework - statically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I have this binary release only of this framework. We instruct our customers to link it dynamically (by linking a universal binary inside our framework).

However - we have a specific customer, which wants to link our framework statically. Is this possible?

We are using good old ObjC, no Swift. We have a private cocoa pod repository, containing our currently dynamic framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually - I created another cocoapod which defines a static library.